# Count most ordered products using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

My **Orders schema** is like this:

```
"products":[
{
"productId":"6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6",
"name":"Shirt Yellow",
"salePrice":19000,
"purchasePrice":16000,
"discount": 100,
"quantity": 2,
"size":"M",
"color":"Green"
},
{
"productId":"6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6",
"name":"Shirt Green",
"salePrice":19000,
"purchasePrice":16000,
"discount": 100,
"quantity": 2,
"size":"M",
"color":"Green"
}],
"storeId":"610a52f7e60d0016e4f98f63",
"storeName":"stylo",
"totalPrice":30000,
"totalPurchasePrice":25000,
"shippingFee":100,
"deliveryInstructions":"Please wear mask while delivery.",
"totalQuantity": 5
}
```

Here, I want to get the 5 most ordered products i.e which are most occurring in the products array.
I wrote the query like this:

```
const popularProducts = await Order.aggregate([
            {
                "$match": {
                    storeId: storeId,
                    status: "Delivered" 
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        "productId": "$products.productId",
                        "productName": "$products.name",
                        //"quantity": {"$sum":"$products.quantity"}
                    },
                    "count": { "$sum": 1}
                }
            },
            {
                "$sort": {count: -1}
            },
            {
                "$limit": NUM_OF_DOCUMENTS
            }
        ])
```

But, it is giving result like in this form:

```
"popularProducts": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Yellow"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 7
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Blue"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 4
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "61084b757a47bd0374b2073d",
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Red",
                        "Shirt Green"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Green"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "61084b757a47bd0374b2073d",
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Yellow",
                        "Shirt Green"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
```

I want each product's count separately but it combines the products which are placed in the same order.  And also gives their result separately. How can I get the result in this form:

```
"popularProducts": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Yellow"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 8
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Blue"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 4
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "61084b757a47bd0374b2073d",
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Red",
                    ]
                },
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "productId": [
                        "6109b819d3eb7e20a8bea1d6"
                    ],
                    "productName": [
                        "Shirt Green"
                    ]
                },
                "count": 7
            },
            
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

Answers assumes that you have many stores, and those stores make many orders,
and you want to find from one specific store which products are more often sold.

Unwind makes from each member of the array 1 document, and replace root makes that member to be the document, and then you can do the group/sort that you already did.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$storeId",
              "610a52f7e60d0016e4f98f63"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$status",
              "Delivered"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$products"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$products"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "productId": "$productId",
        "productName": "$name"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$quantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Run code online](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1CfD1PDNoZc)

If you can next time

- data in (give enough to test the query)
- query semi-finished or/and explain what you want to do
- data out (they should come from the data-in)

Comment: Thanks, @Takis _ for your time, I ran this query but it is giving me a null result.

Comment: the query code is online(go that link i sended and run it) and it is working(its your data i only added 1 field status : delivered because you were using it in the query). If you can send the some of that data that give you null results, because with the data you gave its working.